# Spring Security - Authentication's username is null in AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring, authentication, null, spring-security

I have a Customer class which has all the account info.(it does NOT extend Spring's userdetails.User class)
I'm trying to do some stuff after a successful login (e.g. set new last login time). To achieve this I set up a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

In the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method I try to get the username from the `Authentication` object. This object however is a `User` object. If I try to get the `username` from it I get null.
Can I somehow manage to make the `Authority` object a `Customer` object? Or does my Customer class have to extend the User class?

**Update**

Some more details:

I have my User class. It is completely self written and doesn't implement or extend any interface/class. I do not have a class that implements a UserDetailsService. The `<form-login>` part of my `applicationContext-security.xml` looks like this:

```
<form-login login-page="/index.htm"
                authentication-success-handler-ref='authSuccHandler'
                authentication-failure-handler-ref='authFailureHandler'
                default-target-url='/library/login.htm'
                always-use-default-target='true'/>
```

Theh `authSuccHandler` looks like this: (The necessary bean definition is in place)

```
public class PostSuccessfulAuthenticationHandler extends  SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
{
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            userService.trackUserLogin(authentication.getName()); //NullPointerException
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
}
```

The form redirects to `j_spring_security_check`

Comment: Can you please add more details on what specific configurations you have made that are non-standard (e.g. UserDetailsService, custom filters, authentication providers, etc.). It's a little hard to tease out exactly what you have customized and how you are trying to override the default expected set of Spring Security implementation classes. Also, please let us know what version you're using.

Comment: Added some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the method you are looking for is getPrincipal on Authentication.  Then you have to case the object that comes back to your custom class.

```
User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Authentication` cannot be `User`, since they don't inherit each other.

If your `UserDetailsService` produces a custom `UserDetails`, you should be able to obtain it by calling `getDetails()` on `Authentication`.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Authentication's getDetails() my Customer class implements UserDetails, still I get a ClassCastException. If I use Authentication's getPrincipal() the returned object is of type User and the username is null. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When the request comes into the authentication success handler, it expects you to redirect to the desired `URL`. Use the following to redirect to the desired page like `home.htm`.
This will work definitely!
The modified code is given below. Check it and let me know if you have any issues.

```
 public class PostSuccessfulAuthenticationHandler extends  SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
  {
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        userService.trackUserLogin(authentication.getName()); //NullPointerException
        response.sendRedirect("home.htm");
        //super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```